# Selenium Variable not working

Tags: variables, selenium, ide

I'm trying complete an online form with date variables. The table looks like this:

```
store  CourseStartDate  11/01/2015

type    name=AA7iA      ${CourseStartDate}
```

It runs great in Selenium, no errors. But, in the application I'm using Selenium IDE enters the actual text `${CourseStartDate}`.

What do I have wrong here?

I know it's something really simple and stupid but I can't find an answer anywhere and I've spent hours looking.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for store is wrong. It should be : store value variable.

So try as :

```
store 11/01/2015 CourseStartDate 

type name=AA7iA ${CourseStartDate}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick. I knew it was a stupid mistake.